# Spring cloud stream app, Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm testing spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka. Got error below.

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:69)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:63)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:43)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$AutoAcknowledgingChannelForwardingMessageListener.doOnMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:171)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.AbstractDecodingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractDecodingMessageListener.java:50)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$4$1.doWithRetry(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:607)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:154)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$4.onMessage(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:604)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.QueueingMessageListenerInvoker$KafkaMessageDispatchingSubscriber.onNext(QueueingMessageListenerInvoker.java:221)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.QueueingMessageListenerInvoker$KafkaMessageDispatchingSubscriber.onNext(QueueingMessageListenerInvoker.java:209)
at reactor.core.processor.util.RingBufferSubscriberUtils.route(RingBufferSubscriberUtils.java:67)
at reactor.core.processor.RingBufferProcessor$BatchSignalProcessor.run(RingBufferProcessor.java:789)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:153)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
... 32 common frames omitted
```

My StreamApplication.java

```
package de.codecentric;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding({PersonProcessor.class, LogProcessor.class})
public class StreamApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StreamApplication.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(LogProcessor.CHANNEL)
    public void logEvent(EventLog el) {
        System.out.println("Received event log: " + el.id);
    }

    @StreamListener(PersonProcessor.CHANNEL)
    public void logPerson(Person p) {
        System.out.println("Received person: " + p.name);
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = PersonProcessor.CHANNEL, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "3000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<Person> timerMessageSource() {
        return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Person()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = LogProcessor.CHANNEL, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "3000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<EventLog> logMessageSource() {
        return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(new EventLog()).build();
    }

    public static class EventLog {
        private static int seq = 0;
        public String id = seq++ + "";
    }

    public static class Person {
        private static int seq = 0;
        public String name = "hi " + seq++;
    }
}
```

LogProcessor.java

```
package de.codecentric;

import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;


public interface LogProcessor {
    String CHANNEL = "logs";

    @Output(LogProcessor.CHANNEL)
    MessageChannel output();

    @Input(LogProcessor.CHANNEL)
    SubscribableChannel input();
}
```

PersonProcessor.java

```
package de.codecentric;

import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;


public interface PersonProcessor {
    String CHANNEL = "person";

    @Output(PersonProcessor.CHANNEL)
    MessageChannel output();

    @Input(PersonProcessor.CHANNEL)
    SubscribableChannel input();
}
```

I can also see output:

Received person: hi 0
  Received event log: 0
  Received event log: 4
  Received person: hi 4
  Received event log: 9
  Received person: hi 9

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this can help, but I had the very same exception and I found out that the problem was a @RefreshScope annotation in my code (I see that you're not including this in your code... but just in case you removed from the posted snippets thinking it was not relevant): see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/461

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but your input and output channels need different destination names - e.g.

`CHANNELIN = personIn`, `CHANNELOUT = personOut`.

A processor is not intended to send messages to itself; it's intended to receive a message, process it, and send the result to a different destination.

Processors don't generate messages themselves - that's the purpose of a source.

Comment: Just adding to what Gary said above: each channel is a separate bean and the name of the bean is of the argument of the `@Input/@Output` annotation (and defaulted to the name of the method), so your setup effectively has the two beans clashing with each other. Separate channels must have separate names (We should be better a setup like yours identifying as an error condition, rather than failing to bind).  They can be configured to the same `destination` though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by upgrade my spring cloud version (from Camden SR7 to Dalston SR4).